# Delete entries from sqlalchemy database if they exists for longer time than expected i.e. if the timestamp in the entry is less than cutoff time

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a problem with deleting entries from my sqlalchemy database based on the timestamp value.
So, I am creating this database called **systemTransaction.db** that has a same table name that stores entries of systems and their timestamps. An example entry would be:

```
[id: 1, system: sytem123, time: 2023-8-22 11:49:23]
```

Here time is a timestamp column in my table which has been created as follows:

```
timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=(datetime.now().strptime(datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))
```

Now, I have a cutoff time that I want to set for 2 days let's say, which I am doing as follows:

```
 Days = 2
 cutoff = ((datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=Days)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
 cutoff = datetime.strptime(cutoff, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

If I print this cutoff time I get

```
2023-08-22 13:55:52
```

which is a datetime.datetime class. I need to somehow compare timestamp from the entries to this cutoff time and if the cutoff time is more than the timestamp, then I need to delete those entries since those are entries couple of days older already.

I tried comparing them like this:

```
systemTransaction.query.filter(systemTransaction.timestamp <= cutoff).all()
```

which should give me all the entries that satisfy the condition but this never get resolved and is unable to compare datetime.datetime class of cutoff with sqlquery class.

In other words, how do I compare my cutoff time with the timestamp in the entries and subsequently delete those entries based on whether they exceed two days or not.

Any help is highly appreciated and thank you for your time!

Comment: Q1: What do you mean by "this never get resolved"?

Comment: Q2: how many entries do you usually have to delete? How many would remain in the table? (just order of magnitude).

Comment: When I say this never get resolved, I mean it never satisfies that condition. I basically need a command that would filter the table for entries that are older than cutoff time. Above command does not filter that at the moment

Comment: I usually have 20 entries at one time, could be more than that but typically 20 to 30 entries I would say.

Comment: Ok, i see. What I do not understand is why you convert a datatype "DATE[TIME]" to "STRING" and back. I think that if you work only with DATEs on both DB and Python level, the mistake will be solved.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work and the issue was not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically deletion using ORM ([documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/dml.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.delete), [examples](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_update.html#the-delete-sql-expression-construct)):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, delete
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

CUT_OFF_DAYS = 2

engine = create_engine(YOUR_CONNECTION_STRING)

with Session(engine) as session:
    cut_off_date = datetime.utcnow()  # see notes below
    cut_off_date -= timedelta(days=CUT_OFF_DAYS)

    statement = delete(systemTransaction).where(
        systemTransaction.timestamp <= cut_off_date)

    result = session.execute(statement)
    print(f'Total rows deleted: {result.rowcount}')

    session.commit()
```

There are a number of things that can interfere. `default` argument should have a callable value. Otherwise `timestamp` column may got the module import time, which is supposedly not what is expected.

Here is the better way to declare `timestamp` column:

```
from datetime import datetime

...

timestamp = db.Column(
    db.DateTime(), 
    default=datetime.utcnow  # a function, not it's result
)
```

It's even better to delegate the calculation to the SQL engine. But in that case you either have to make `DateTime` column time zone aware or explicitly define `server_default` according to the SQL dialect in use.

Time zone awareness and `now` at SQL server:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

...

timestamp2 = db.Column(
    db.DateTime(timezone=True), 
    server_default=func.now())
```

No time zone, but cast to UTC in case of PostgreSQL:

```
from sqlalchemy import text

...

sql_utcnow = text('(now() at time zone \'utc\')')

timestamp3 = db.Column(
    db.DateTime, 
    server_default=sql_utcnow)
```